# jQuery <audio> fade out with animate is choppy

Tags: jquery, html, audio, fade

I've been looking for a solid way to fade out audio playback using jQuery. Animate seems to be the cleanest way to accomplish this, but the fading out ends up sounding choppy/staticy with the sound files I'm using. (Check out the fiddle to hear the choppiness)

```
<button id="fade">Fade</button>
<audio id="music" preload="auto" >
    <source src="http://kegham.com/download/sound/c0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

$('#fade').click(function(){
    var sound = $('#music').get(0).cloneNode();
    sound.play();
    $(sound).animate({volume: 0}, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MrHam/AmM8n/

As far as I can understand, this choppiness is me hearing the increments in decreasing volume that need to happen to hit 0 volume. A duration of 500 for the fading is rather short, so we have a greater chance of hearing the increments.

I tried applying some easing in hopes of reducing the choppiness, but it did not help. Is there any way to make this audio fade out smoother? Is jQuery and HTML5 audio not the best way to accomplish this fading effect?

(Currently testing in Chrome only.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the ears are a lot more sensitive to this sort of thing than our eyes, which is what the animation timer is built for.  Short of using the WebAudio API, I don't think there is a way to do this.  If you do switch to the WebAudio API though, there are a few options you can use.